# How can I import a list of Waypoints to a Drone by using DJI Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I created a Polygon in a GIS application. I can export the Polygon to a KML or any other required format.

I need to define a mission's Waypoints for my drone based on the Polygon that I have.

Is there a simple way to directly feed the Polygon missions Waypoints to a Drone without a MapView?

I have to use DJI Windows SDK, but I saw [this sample](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/GSDemo.html#setup-the-map-view) that interacts with the user to define a mission's Waypoints in a MapView. My scenario is different. I already have  Waypoints, and I just need to import them.

**Update 1:**
Please note that DJI SDK for iOS and Android are very mature, feature-rich and proven tested. However, it is not the same with DJU Windows SDK. The SDK target platform is vague, but reading its example, I think it runs only on  UWP platform. That is why the question mentions **DJI Windows SDK** explicitly. I know the SDK for Android or iOS provides much higher quality and features.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add them to the list using the Latitude and Longitude. You also need the altitude for each point. Make a for loop for all the points that you need or do this code once, use the config dialog then upload and start the mission.

```
// Create a waypoint instance
Waypoint mWaypoint1 = new Waypoint(Latitude, Longitude, altitude);

//check if the mission's builder is null
if (waypointMissionBuilder != null) {
  if (waypointList.size() > 2)
    configWayPointMission();

  waypointList.add(mWaypoint1);
  waypointMissionBuilder.waypointList(waypointList).waypointCount(waypointList.size());
}
else {
  waypointMissionBuilder = new WaypointMission.Builder();
  waypointList.add(mWaypoint1);
  waypointMissionBuilder.waypointList(waypointList).waypointCount(waypointList.size());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Can you please confirm that this is a general .NET code, and it does not have dependancy on UWP ?

Comment: @AllanXu This code is from Android Studio (form DJI) so I have no idea about it. I assume it might have a few changes between platforms but the idea is the same

Comment: please see my Update 1. Makes sense?

Comment: @AllanXu Yes, I can't find any sample code from DJI for windows but i assume the logic is the same and so does the Waypoint mission class. Make a list or an array of points, check if you have 3 or more points if you do then start the mission

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't used the Windows SDK, but I imagine it is similar to the Mobile SDK. For mobile, you would just put the waypoints in an array/arraylist and load them into the mission all at once.

I'm not sure if you need to convert the KML into waypoints or if you already have the waypoints. In the former case, you would need to parse the KML. Assuming you have the waypoints parse, then you need to use WaypointMissionManager and WaypointMissionHandler to load the mission and then start the mission.

You can use the load/upload mission functions. The paramater of load mission is [WaypointMission](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/WaypointMission/WaypointMissionHandler.html#value_waypointmission_inline) where you can set the number of waypoints and other related info.

For example in Android, I do the following:

```
    ArrayList<Waypoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < wplist.size(); i++) {
        double lat = wplist.get(i).latitude;
        double lon = wplist.get(i).longitude;
        //each dji waypoint corresponds to the predetermined waypoints
        Waypoint djiWaypoint = new Waypoint(lat, lon, altitude);
        //Point Gimbal down for each waypoint
        djiWaypoint.gimbalPitch = gimbalPitchDown;
        //add waypoint to waypoints array
        waypoints.add(djiWaypoint);
    }

    //initiate builder and add waypoints to it- not yet built
    waypointMissionBuilder = new WaypointMission.Builder();
    waypointMissionBuilder.waypointList(waypoints).waypointCount(waypoints.size());
    totalNumberOfWaypointsInMission = waypointMissionBuilder.getWaypointCount();

    //Prepare mission by updating configure and instantiate waypointMissionBuilder
    configWayPointMission();
    //upload Mission
    uploadWaypointMission();
```